# Is there a way to search content I've touched?

Tags: support, comments, edits, questions, search

I believe I've finally discovered the answer to the question was ... 42 ... or something like that.  The only problem is that, many months after the question was asked, I now need to find the question.

Google searches and Stack Exchange searches have not found the question.  But I know this was both one I edited (to clean up the English) and one I commented on.

Looking at my own activity tab, this narrows it down to around 500 questions.  500 is quite a lot to read through one by one.  *I need to further narrow this search.*

Is there any way I can search my own activity?  Specifically I'd like to search through *questions* I've edited and commented on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such a complicated search practically begs for a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1060807/search-in-edited-commented-questions?UserId=453851). Since comments can be deleted, I've made that part optional.

Here is a list of questions you edited containing the word 'code':

[image]

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. If you want to experiment, [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1060807) the query, before or after you've read the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your profile (click your flair in the upper right corner of the page).

To view edits, click the "X posts edited" link on the right side, under Impact.

To view your comments, click the "All actions" tab, then the "Comments" subtab.

Comment: I'm not looking for a full list of everything I've edited, I'm trying to filter that (very long) list with a search.